# math.sqrt in a break statement

Tags: python, math

I'm very new to python. Currently working on a lab which is dealing with break statements. I have this line of code

```
from math import sqrt 
for i in range(1001, 0, -1):     
    root = sqrt(i) 
    if root == int(root):      
        print i 
        break
```

The question asks me to change the first line to import math (without import sqrt) and to keep the other lines the same. That leaves me with this:

```
import math
math.sqrt(i)
for i in range(1001, 0, 01):
    root = sqrt(i)
    if root == int(root):
        print i
        break
```

When running it, I come up with a NameError message that name 'sqrt' is not defined. How do I fix this code without changing the first line?

Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
for i in range(1001, 0, -1):     
    root = math.sqrt(i) 
    if root == int(root):      
        print i 
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how imports work. If you just want to mention the math module without mentioning the square root function up front, do

```
import math
for i in range(1001, 0, -1):
    root = math.sqrt(i)
    if root == int(root):
        print i
        break
```

Note how that works. The statement `import math` tells Python to note all the functions in the math module without adding all their names to the current environment. In other words, Python can quickly use the math module, but the only name it currently understands is `math`.

When you need to use a function that is in the math module, just prefix it with `math.`, as in `math.sqrt`. Python knows where `math` is, so it uses that module to find the `sqrt` function and uses it. But do this every time you use the `sqrt` or other function. No need to declare is separately in advance, just do that to `math`.

This keeps the number of names down to a reasonable size (a problem in large programs) but still enables Python to use many modules.